# After clicking on my listview i want it to extract the phonenumber then send SMS to the clicked phonenumber

Tags: java, android, android-listview, sqlite

I am very new to android and do not have much knowledge about java but am required due to school project. I need the phonenumber to be extracted and send SMS when a particular name or number is clicked on the listview. I am stuck. Thanks in advance. Now i only manage to send a SMS to this number "123456" whenever i click any item from the list. This are all my codes.

Contacts

```
package com.Elson.ProjectVersion;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;


public class Contacts implements Comparable<Contacts> {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private int Phone;
    private int Email;
    private Date date;
    private double runningAverage;




    public Contacts(String name, int Phone,  Date date) {
        this.name = name;
        this.Phone = Phone;
        this.date = null;
    }

    public Contacts(long id, String name,int Phone) {
        this.id=id;
        this.Phone=Phone;
        this.name= (name);

    }


    public long getId() {

        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getPhone() {
        return Phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(int Phone) {
        this.Phone = Phone;
    }
    public String getname() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setname(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Date getDate() {
        return null;
    }

    public long getDateEpoch(){
        return date.getTime()/1000;
    }
    public void setDateEpoch(long seconds){
        date= new Date (seconds*1000);
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }




    public void setRunningAverage(double runningAverage) {
        this.runningAverage = runningAverage;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object that){
        Contacts bs = (Contacts) that;

        return this.date.equals(bs.date);
      }


    @Override



    public String toString() {
        String result;

        if(date != null) {
            DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
            result = df.format(date) + "" + name + "" + Phone ; 
    }
    else {
          result = name + "" + Phone ; 
    }
        return result;
    }





    @Override
    public int compareTo(Contacts another) {    
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

}
```

SendActivity

```
package com.Elson.ProjectVersion;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class SendActivity extends ListActivity {

Bundle savedInstanceState;
private ArrayList<Contacts> allContacts;
private Button AddContactsButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
    setContentView(R.layout.send_layout);


    // get data from the App
    ContactsActivityApplication app = (ContactsActivityApplication) getApplication();
    allContacts = app.getAllContacts();

    // View --- Adapter ------ Data

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Contacts>(this, R.layout.history_row, R.id.textStart, allContacts));

    final ListView listView = this.getListView();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Contacts selectedContax = (Contacts) listView.getSelectedItem();
            //sendSMS(String.valueOf("123456"), "Hi");
        }
    }

    );
}

private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, SendActivity.class), 0);
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);
}

public void AddContactstoListClickHandler (View v){

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EnterContactsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

Comment: Please try and cut down some of the code in your post. This is way too much to reasonably expect someone to sift through.

Comment: You're off to a good start with a project that compiles and that can send an SMS to a known number. We'll provide help with specific issues, but this is your homework problem, so let us know what you've tried and what specifically isn't working. Have you been able to attach an event handler to the list? Are you having trouble just extracting the phone number? (Also, in addition to just "too much code", you have lots of unnecessary blank lines!)

Comment: The above code is what i have came out through more than 30 hours of tutorial in total regarding sqldatabases and everything. On my starting page I have a listview that shows the contact that i have added through another activity where there is the edittext input for name and phone number. It successfully adds the phonenumber and name to the listview. Now i need to extract the phonenumber from the itemclick on the listview to automatically send a message to my sensor. But now i only know how to send to a particular number. Thanks for the help in advance. New to stackoverflow. Sorry!

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I have already edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

Well your question is not clear and reading all the code in time consuming. What I understood from your question is you are displaying a list of numbers in listView and when a user taps on a listView item, you want to send message to that number. So try the following code.

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

String phoneNumber = (String) l.getItemAtPosition(position);

// send message to the number stored in phoneNumber
}
```

With your code, you can do like this:

```
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        String phoneNumber = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

        // Don't store the item returned by this method in Contact object.
    }
}

);
```

Comment: Sorry i have edited the post already. Can i still use this function with the above code? Or do i need to edit. Sorry i really have bare minimum knowledge about java.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use an own created class MyContact instead of Contacts,

```
public class MyContact{
    String Phone;
    String Name;
    //...

    public MyContact (String Phone, String Name) //or more {
        this.Phone = Phone;
        this.Name = Name;
        //...
    }
}

String myText; //the short message

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        MyContact selected = allContacts.get(position); //allContacts[position];
        Intent intentSms = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intentSms.setData(Uri.fromParts("sms", selected.Phone, null));
        intentSms.putExtra("sms_body", myText);
        startActivity(intentSms);
    }
```

Comment: Can i have an example on how i should get my number from selected contax and how toget the item at position? Know it's too much to ask but thanks for all of ur time.

Comment: No. I have not declared anything for selectedContax yet. What should i declare?

Comment: please post what are the children of view and parent in the itemclicklistener (use breakpoints and watches)

Comment: u mean the xml file of the addcontacts page?

Comment: no i mean set a breakpoint in "onItemClick" and watch the type of view (i edited my solution, see whats new!)

Comment: Hey actually i have this class. I edit the above and please help me see if the above still works.

Comment: should work -> sendSMS(String.valueOf(selected.getPhone()), "Hi"); are you sure phone is an int? maybe you want to save "-" or "+" or "/" in your number???  did you implement PERMISSION send_sms in your manifest?

Comment: Yes i did change it to string. Yes and i did implement the PERMISSION. Umm. Is it possible to have private messages in stackoverflow? I would need some help if u are free. :)